# What's the actual font used by Firefox to render an element?

Tags: css, firefox

Yes, I know about addons such as Firebug or the Web Developer Toolbar that allow one
to see the font-family specification pertaining to a specific element, but how can I
find out which actual font is Firefox using to render the element?

To give you an example, suppose I declare, say `font-family: "Georgia", "Verdana", serif;`.
Now, the *Georgia* font is not installed in the system, and Firefox thus picks the next on
the list (*Verdana*).  Is there some addon out there that will give me access to this info?

Note that I need this functionality for development, not for detection at runtime inside Javascript.

Comment: There's a similar question on SO that actually has a *real* answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884177/how-can-i-determine-what-font-a-browser-is-actually-using-to-render-some-text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing like this exists, as far as I know.

It would be easy to test fonts in turn by using something like this:

```
.myElement {
    font-family:georgia, monospace;
}
```

In this case it's very clear whether Georgia is used or not, as it's not a monospace font.

You could use a modification of this script to add a bookmarklet in your browser for testing fonts: http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  It's a pity no precise solution exists, but your suggestion is good enough.