# What font is displayed?

Tags: html, firefox, css, browser, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I determine what font a browser is actually using to render some text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884177/how-can-i-determine-what-font-a-browser-is-actually-using-to-render-some-text)

My CSS style goes as "font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;" for the whole page. It looks like Verdana is being used instead on some parts. I need to somehow verify this.

I've tried copy-paste from my browser into MS Word, but the font is not preserver.

Is there some tool to determine which font is actually being rendered for a page or section of text?

Firebug gives me the list of fonts as above, but I don't see a way to determine which one of the fonts is being used.

Comment: I just wanted to answer that you should try pasting in Word, but that does not seem to work for you. Did you try cut and paste from IE? Or another word processor than Word, or a different version of Word?
(this approach does work for me)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Basically, an element is set to use a specific font . If the font set for the element does not exist, it takes the font of the parent element. So, what they do is measure the width of the rendered string. If it matches what they expected for the desired font as opposed to the derived font, it's present.

Here's where I saw it: [Javascript/CSS Font Detector (ajaxian.com; 12 Mar 2007)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4415/)

Also, The [FontFinder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4415/) plugin for Firefox does exactly what you want. After installing, highlight a block of text, right click and go to FontFinder -> Analyze Selection. It will tell you the actual font being used as well as a other information like font-family, spacing, color, etc.

Comment: font finder is the best one I have seen

Comment: font finder worked.. Thanks for the details too

Answer (score -2):

Yes offcourse! You can use firebug a built-in tool in firefox and chrome.

http://getfirebug.com/enable

Comment: I mentioned that firebug gives me the fonts given in CSS styles, not the actual font being used