# Finding out which of the fonts is used

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a paragraph with an inline style like given below:

```
<p style="font-family:georgia,garamond,serif;">
```

My question is that is there a way to find out which of the fonts is being used by my page and what is the selection procedure?

Comment: Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845/detecting-which-font-was-used-in-a-web-page). It answers the same question you're asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting which font was used in a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845/detecting-which-font-was-used-in-a-web-page)

Comment: Here's [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960817/get-computed-font-family-in-javascript) with some more usable answers in it

Comment: @SimplyComplexable No it's not duplicate, this question is about particular element not whole page.

Comment: Can you please clarify you want some JavaScript font detection for particular element or you need something with browser tools detection?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov The question actually asks "which of the fonts is being used by my page", but either way it would be the same process. Determine which fonts are available in the browser and go through the list of possible fonts, eliminating them as you go.

Comment: Deleted my post because if found it unreliable.

Comment: @Mozmith: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

**Dev Tools**

Open dev tools and look for computed styles, you can see which styles are being applied and where...including fonts.

- **Chrome:** https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/09/DevTools-answers-What-font-is-that
- **Firefox:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/View_fonts

Fonts are defined using the `font-family` property. Your browser will look at this list of fonts, starting with the first (moving from left to right), and check to see if the font is available either on the users computer or via `@font-face` at rule. If the font is found, it will load it up, if not, it moves on to the next to try again.

**Get computed font with JavaScript**

```
var el = document.getElementById("id");
var style = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue("font-family");
```

*[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kennethcss/m8c24qyc/)*

*See MDN...*

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue

Comment: As mentioned in the comments on Difster's answer I think this is probably asking about detecting the font dynamically using javascript.

Comment: You are right Kenneth.I would like to find out dynamically which font is being used.

Answer (score 1):

While in your browser, on that page, hit <kbd>F12</kbd>. You should see a section for CSS. What you look for exactly depends on your browser though.

Comment: OP probably wants to find out this information using JavaScript, so that he can use it within his application in some way. Also, F12 only works in Internet Explorer - for example Chrome on Mac is Cmd+Shift+I

Comment: I probably shouldn't be answering questions when I'm sick. LOL 
But F12 works just fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: Ah, it's a great way to spend the time though :P Maybe F12 works on Chrome on Windows - I didn't know that.

Comment: F12 works on most browsers independent of your OS.CTRL+SHIFT+I is the same as just pressing F12.@Toastrackenigma

Answer (score 1):

The browser will render the fonts in order of how you place them. For example, in your code the first font to be tried would be Georgia, then if that wasn't supported by the device or browser it would move on to trying Garamond, and than lastly it would use any serif font the browser and device could support.

> CSS defines a property called font-family that contains an ordered
>   list of fonts. These fonts are supposed to be tried in order, looking
>   both for availability of the font itself, as well as availability of
>   glyphs to draw the current text.[1](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Font_selection)

To which font the browser is using in Chrome hit Crtl + Shift + I and if you click on elements in the html below under style it will show what style is being rendered on the page.

To get the rendered element with javascript see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338217/get-a-css-value-with-javascript)

[Article explain font selection by a browser](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Font_selection)

Comment: And how to determine what of specified are used? This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Edited it to give info on how to do it in JS and within chrome

Comment: It doesn't answer the question still because if you run `window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("p"))["font-family"]` for OP's code it will return whole array `georgia,garamond,serif`, not rendered font name!

Comment: Vadim Ovchinnikov is right.it shows all the font families.i also used other methods.but it gave me the same results.can you be a little more precise?@FattySalami

Comment: yes it is there.under rendered styles in inspector.a good solution but can i find it dynamically using javascript?

Comment: Your right look at the second answer on this link. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884177/how-can-i-determine-what-font-a-browser-is-actually-using-to-render-some-text) it explains how to see the font being used in chrome, firefox and safari

Comment: This answer is old so I would think there is a better way now but [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664045/how-to-get-an-html-elements-style-values-in-javascript) explains how to get the style with JS

Answer (score 0):

try this one

it will get font name which will use in `style`

```js
//using id

var b = document.getElementById("p").style.fontFamily;
console.log(b);

//or using jquery tag selecter

console.log($("p").css('fontFamily'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="p" style="font-family:georgia,garamond,serif;">
```

Comment: I am sorry Bhargav.I dont want to use any 3rd party libraries.Would appreciate i you provide something in Vanilla