# How to know which font is used by browser from CSS font-family list?

Tags: css, webfonts, font-family

In web development, a preferred list of font is put in font-family of CSS as following sample.

```css
font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
```

I want to know which font is chose by browser to display the content. I know I can manual modify the font in `font-family` one by one in browser developer tool and observe the changes of displayed content to identify the font used by browser. But it's too clumsy and require very sharp eyes T_T.

Anyone can know a better way? Thanks very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I determine what font a browser is actually using to render some text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884177/how-can-i-determine-what-font-a-browser-is-actually-using-to-render-some-text)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In [firefox-developer-tools](/questions/tagged/firefox-developer-tools), **Inspector** **>** **Fonts** tab displays "Fonts used" by the currently inspected element. [Edit fonts MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Edit_fonts)

In [google-chrome-devtools](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtools), **Elements** **>** **Computed** tab displays "rendered fonts"
for the currently inspected element. "Even if its name isn’t in the font-family list." [whats-that-font](https://deanhume.com/quick-tip-whats-that-font/) , [Hackernoon](https://hackernoon.com/twelve-fancy-chrome-devtools-tips-dc1e39d10d9d)

Firefox :-

[image]
[image]

Chrome :-

[image]

Thanks, @xuemind for suggested edit

Comment: Yes, it is! So fantastic feature in Firefox. But Vikas Patel gave another suggestion in previous answer. Is it possible to accept 2 answers?

Comment: In Firefox, the third pane of the developer tools was off the right side of the window. I resized the other two panes and found the font tab.

Answer (score 2):

In order if available.
In your example it'll go for Roboto first and keep the next (`"Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif`) as back-up, if it's available.

Comment: thanks for your answer. So, If I don't know what kind of font has been installed in OS, how can I know which font browser choose finally in font-family list?

Answer (score 2):

Hi On mozilla firefox use Font Finder addon .
It is the best addon which will provide u all the styles applying on your element.!

[image]

### Updated

It works as I expect. After **Font Finder** installed, select the target text and choose [*Font Finder>Analyze Selection*] in context menu (right click). It will show the **Font Being Rendered** as following screenshot!
[image]