# Preloading Google Fonts

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, lighthouse

Light House audit is suggesting that I preload key requests, specifically the two google fonts that I'm using in my React app. A Light House member suggested using:

`<link rel="preload" as="style" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Roboto:700" crossorigin>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/" crossorigin>`

I know it's making the request because I see it in the waterfall and I get this console warning:

"The resource https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Roboto:700 was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate as value and it is preloaded intentionally."

Unfortunately the two font do not display in my app anymore. Do I need to define these in my CSS with @font-face or something like that?

Comment: I can't see your code, but I'd guess you *replaced* the `<link rel="stylesheet">` with the `<link rel="preload">`. This is not sufficient. You'll need both, the `preload` and the `stylesheet`.

Comment: So like this?

<link rel="preload" as="style" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Roboto:700" crossorigin>

Comment: Not quite yet. You're not supposed to combine those tags into one but rather preserve both. You'll eventually end up with two `<link>` tags for each font. One for `preload`, one `stylesheet`.

Comment: This works:  
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/" crossorigin>
    <link rel="preload" as="style" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700" crossorigin>
    <link rel="preload" as="style" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" crossorigin>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin>

Comment: Without adding the crossorgin property I get a render blocking stylesheet warning from LightHouse but, this whole endeavor to preload font fonts per Chrome's suggestion as upped my first meaningful paint to 3620ms from 2650ms and lower my lighthouse score from 88 to 79.

Comment: I also tried combining the tags like this:    
<link rel="preload" as="style" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Roboto:700" crossorigin>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Roboto:700" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin>       
Which helped a little bit but, in trying to optimize I have inadvertently slowed everything down...

Answer (score 45):

The correct way to preload a font would be by adding both a `preload` link and a `stylesheet`. A simplified example, based on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content) is as follows:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Preloading fonts</title>

  <link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" as="style">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap">
</head>

<body>
</body>
```

In the above example, the `preload` link will send a request to fetch the font regardless of it being installed or not on the client and then use the `stylesheet` link to properly load and use it.

`preload` is more of a way to tell the browser that a resource will probably be needed, so that it will be requested regardless and then, if you need it or decide to use it, you can.

Further information

- [Preloading content with rel="preload" - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content)
- [Preload your Webfont resources - Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/webfont-optimization#preload_your_webfont_resources)
- [rel="preload" support - Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=link-rel-preload)

Comment: I think you meant to say preload `as="font"`

Comment: @monchisan No, the `as="style"` attribute is correct. Google is serving a CSS which contains the @font-face declarations.

Comment: @Angelos Chalaris I think its preload CSS only not the fonts

Comment: you don't need `crossorigin` for `preload`? thanks for your help!

Comment: This will NOT preload the font. This will only preload the stylesheet which tells the browser where to fetch the font when it wants to.

Comment: @AndréChalella is correct, this doesn't preload the font.

Answer (score 41):

It is recommended that you preconnect, then preload, and then finally load as follows:

```
<link rel='preconnect' href='https://fonts.gstatic.com' crossorigin>
<link rel='preload' as='style' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans|Roboto:wght@700&display=swap'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans|Roboto:wght@700&display=swap'>
```

You cannot just preconnect and/or preload, you still need to load as usual.
Then you just specify any font weight that is not the default for that given font by using `:wght@700`, for example. Between successive fonts you put the pipe `|` sign.

Comment: useful resource: https://www.cdnplanet.com/blog/faster-google-webfonts-preconnect

Comment: Most complete comment. I've noticed that Google has recently changed the URL replacing *css* with *css2*.

Comment: you don't need `crossorigin` for the preload, only preconnect?

Comment: Thank you @Alex. I updated my code with css2 as you pointed out.

Comment: Yes, @Crashalot you do need crossorigin and it is already in my first line of code.

Comment: Why is preconnect needed if preload is immediately after the preconnect? Won't it connect and load immediately in either case?

Comment: The 'preconnect' is to give your website a heads up and gets it connected to Google. The preload indicates what you will be loading. And finally, 
you load the font(s) using https://fonts.googleapis.com

Comment: @MichaelMoriarty Thanks! I am still not convinced this preloads the fonts though. In my app I use `...Roboto&wght=300;400;700;900` and I do not use 900 until some time has passed.  In my network tab, 300, 400 and 700 loads (because they are used instantly), and I don't see a network call for 900 until literally 900 is used later in the app causing FOUT.

Comment: @user1059939 Check out this article: https://nitropack.io/blog/post/font-loading-optimization You may need to experiment with different font-display choices to help avoid FOUT

Answer (score 1):

google always serve font from same domain `fonts.gstatic.com`

so preload it before adding style.

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Roboto:700">
```

Comment: What you say is ambiguous. The 'preconnect' is to give your website a heads up and gets it connected to Google. The preload that you are missing indicates what you will be loading. And finally, you load the font(s) as you indicated using the api.