# How to apply <link rel=preload> to @font-face?

Tags: html, css, font-face

Google recommends "Consider using `<link rel=preload>` to prioritize fetching resources that are currently requested later in page load." But no example of how we should use this when using the @font-face method.
Should I switch to HTML font loading method instead?

What I'm using now to load my custom font:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Custom';
    src: url("../fonts/Custom-Bold.eot");
    src: local("☺"), url("../fonts/Custom-Bold.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/Custom-Bold.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/Custom-Bold.svg") format("svg");
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
  }
  
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Custom';
    src: url("../fonts/Custom-Heavy.eot");
    src: local("☺"), url("../fonts/Custom-Heavy.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/Custom-Heavy.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/Custom-Heavy.svg") format("svg");
    font-weight: 800;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preloading Google Fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50824181/preloading-google-fonts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommendation is to apply the **preload** to your link tags, not in the style itself.

So for instance if your css code is in a file called "fonts.css", you would put the following line in the HTML where you are going to access it:

```
<link rel="preload" as="style" href="fonts.css">
```

You would then be telling the page to preload your "fonts.css" file. The **"as"** here should be whatever the actual resource is, so if instead of a style sheet you actually wanted to use a font file, just change the "**as='style'**" to "**as='font'**".

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I have the @font-face inside my main style.css file. I should probably move it into its own css file.

Comment: Note that this will preload the CSS file only, not the actual font files