# How do I now which font family is used for text on web-page

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, fonts

I'm doing some web development.

I have a component (a text) which has the following font family defined:

```
font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
```

How do I know which font family from these is used in my browser?

I use Mozilla currently and I open Inspector, and bot *Rules* and *Computed* tab show: `font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;`

There is also *Fonts* tab showing this:
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845/detecting-which-font-was-used-in-a-web-page

Comment: As the question is phrased and presented currently, it appears that you have already answered your own question, as the *rules* and *computed* tabs both indicate *which font family is being used*. If you want to know *which* `font-family`, *out of the **specified range** of font-families*, is being used, consider clarifying your question to indicate this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting which font was used in a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845/detecting-which-font-was-used-in-a-web-page)

Comment: Just to clarify guys, I think what the the poster wants is for his application to know which font was used. It's pretty easy to debug or visually know but he wants the application to detect what was used.

Comment: @crimson589 This appears to be the assumption. Although, the OP is the only one who should clarify this.

Comment: I'm looking for an answer similar to what @miguel-svq provided, but also for Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In chrome, using the inspector, select the exact TAG you want to check. Select the "computed" styles tab, at the end you will find wich font of the stack have been used. For 'code' here the fontstack is `Consolas,Menlo,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New,monospace,sans-serif` and you can check that in my computer it used exactly "Consolas" (bottom-right on the image)

EDIT: Added FF screenshot. Same work in firefox, just select the specific TAG you want to check.

[image: chrome inspector, rendered font]
[image: firefox inspector, rendered font]

Comment: Like! I switched to Firefox lately, do you know if there is something similar in Firefox?

Comment: Exactly the same. Just select the single item you want to check. You posted  the answer with your question :)

Comment: OK, not exactly the same then, but the Inspector - Fonts tab.

Answer (score 0):

try this code first:

```
font-family: "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
```

if text appearence has changed then it was Roboto else:

```
font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
```

if changed = Helvetica

and so on..

Comment: change this in your browsers inspector

Comment: Don't like this method. I was looking for font info in inspector, as miquel-svq said. Hopefully there is something similar in Firefox.