# Conditional CSS declaration

Tags: css

I have a theme with the following CSS rule:

```css
.xcode {
    font-family: SFMono-Regular,Menlo,Consolas,"Liberation Mono","Courier New",Courier,monospace;
    font-size: 75%;
}
```

It is basically a soup of different fonts from Apple, Windows, Linux which look differently sized at 75%. I'd like the size to be, say, 90% when Consolas is selected, 80% when Liberation Mono is selected, and stay as it is otherwise. Is this possible using CSS only? How?

Comment: No, there's no way as of today. With script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845/how-to-detect-which-one-of-the-defined-font-was-used-in-a-web-page

Comment: @connexo -- Using another unit doesn't really help, and won't change each font's internal size differences.