# Set default fallback font for HTML page

Tags: html, css, fonts

Is it possible to set a fallback font that will apply to all text elements on the page?

Let's say I have an html page like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...
<p style="font-family:Arial">Text 1</p>
<p style="font-family:Comic Sans">Text 2</p>
<p style="font-family:Agave">Text 3</p>
...
</body>
</html>
```

And I want `Courier` to be used as a fallback font on this whole page. Basically, to turn this page into

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...
<p style="font-family:Arial,Courier">Text 1</p>
<p style="font-family:Comic Sans,Courier">Text 2</p>
<p style="font-family:Agave,Courier">Text 3</p>
...
</body>
</html>
```

but without explicitly writing `",Courier"` in every text element?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font_fallbacks.asp

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen Could you elaborate? How does it answer my question?

Comment: you can use google fonts for this there you only need to mention the font name in the starting of the html

Answer (score 2):

With a *CSS custom property* you can precisly control when a fallback font is used.

Instead of `<tag style="font-family:...">` you will need to use `<tag style="--family:...">`, where `--family` is a previously defined *CSS custom property*:

- Define variable `--family` in `:root` with a default preferred font family.
- Make all (relevant) tags use the `--family` property. In the snippet I use `body *` to make **all** tags inside the document body use `--family`, but instead a (list of) class(es) would be the preferred method.

Below simple tester code shows a list of text with several imported fonts and their fallback behaviour.

```css
/* A few imported font families */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cairo:wght@400&family=Kanit:wght@400&family=Noto+Sans:wght@400&family=Poppins:wght@400&display=swap');

/* Selected default font when none defined */
:root  { --family: 'Poppins' }

/* Use font defined in --family or fallback to Courier */
body, body * { font-family: var(--family), Courier; }
```

```html
<div>Test, :root defined 'default' --family (Poppins)</div>
<div style="--family: Cairo">Test, Cairo imported font --family</div>
<div style="--family: Kanit">Test, Kanit imported font --family</div>
<div style="--family: Noto+Sans">Test, Noto Sans imported font --family</div>
<div style="--family: Poppins">Test, Poppins imported font --family</div>

<div style="--family: initial">Test, browser default --family (your preferred font, usually Arial)</div>
<div style="--family: Arial">Test, default Arial --family</div>
<div style="--family: not-exist, Arial">Test, none existent, Arial fallback --family</div>
<div style="--family: not-exist">Test, none existent, Courier fallback --family</div>
```

Comment: This is very a cool way, thank you, I learned some new things from your answer! But it doesn't seem to be exactly what I'm looking for becayse you would still have to modify every text elements by prepending `--family`, right? It doesn't seem to be much different than appending `,Courier`

Comment: No, it is not the same: CSS does the copying for you. `:root { --family: 'Poppins' }` is just an example, using `:root {--family: inherit }` instead will assign any parent defined font. My browser will set the default to *san-serif* (in browser font settings I assigned *Noto Sans* to *sans-serif*). By using `body, body * { ... }` the proposed construction works like a charm without repeating *Courier* all the time. However...

Comment: I also suggested to change `body *` to something more appropriate, so you still can use other fonts without using `--family`. Also, instead of `, Courier` you could define another variable like `:root { --fallback: Courier }` and write `body, body * { font-family: var(--family), var(--fallback); }`. This way you have default fallback font *Courier*, but you can overwrite it any time with a font you require. You just need to fiddle with this to get the combination that works best for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Rene nails it with [CSS custom properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77238085/19068), but I'll leave the rest of my original answer here for the sake of explanation and an alternative approach.

---

CSS will try each font listed in the `font-family` in turn until it finds one that is supported or gets to the end and uses the *browser's* default.

There is absolutely no provision in CSS for falling back to a different rule from earlier in the cascade or changing the browser's default.

---

The closest you could come would be to try to iterate over all the relevant elements using JavaScript and try to detect the font in use that way. This is, however, not something the browser provides an API for.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845/how-to-detect-which-one-of-the-defined-font-was-used-in-a-web-page) asks about detecting that, but most of the answers completely miss the point of the question. The one that does understand it points to [this blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20090226190333/http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect) where the author attempts to work out which font is in use by measuring the width of the rendered text and comparing it to the expected width for the font.

This strikes me as being time consuming to set up for any but a small number of fonts. I suspect it is also very likely to get broken by different rendering engines and variations in fonts. Then you run into the issue that it would render everything and then rerender the things that you change, likely with a visible change of font and layout.

With all those drawbacks, I wouldn't go down that route.

---

Depending on your goals, you could consider using a tool like [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/) to generate your CSS and then use a `@mixin` (this would make changing the fallback easier, keep your source code more manageable, and maybe save a little typing, but wouldn't skim any bytes off the result):

```scss
@mixin fontFamily($value) {
  font-family: $value, Courier, monospace;
}

.foo {
  @include fontFamily("Arial");
}

.bar {
  @include fontFamily("Comic Sans");
}

.baz {
  @include fontFamily("Agave");
}
```

… although this would require that you replace the `style` attribute with something you could target with a selector.

Comment: Noticed your update, tnx!

Answer (score -1):

Just use 1 style for whole page (*) but set that font-family as !important

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
...
  <style>
    * {
      font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
...
    <p style="font-family:Arial">Text 1</p>
    <p style="font-family:Comic Sans">Text 2</p>
    <p style="font-family:Agave">Text 3</p>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Anything you write without !important will lose its importance, as the more specific css styles you mention in

elements will be applied. However,if you use !important, the general styles can't be overwritten.

Please try and let me know if it works on your side. Was working on mine.

Comment: That will cause the rule `font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace !important;` to **completely override** the rule `font-family:Arial`. It **won't** use `Courier` as a fallback when `Arial` isn't available. It won't even try to use `Arial`.

Comment: oh that's what you meant.

have you tried reversing the styles? You could individually set each <p> element's style as arial !important. and also set it as courier. this way it'll try to first set it as arial, if it doesn't find that it'll set as courier.

<p style="font-family:Arial !important; font-family: Courier...">Text 1</p>

might look something like this. but yes you will have to write courier in every statement then I'm afraid :(

Comment: That won't work. The rule `font-family:Arial !important;` will completely override the rule `font-family: Courier` and it will *never* try to use Courier.